# Is Blazer server SSR and SPA?

Tags: c#, blazor, single-page-application, server-side-rendering, blazor-server-side

I heard that the Blazer server is SSR(server-side rendering).
By the way, I know that the Blazer server is a single page apps (SPA).
Is the Blazer server both SSR and SPA?
Then, does the Blazer server first receive data through SSR method and then receive data through CSR method to implement the SPA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on your definitions.

Blazor Server is `Server Side Rendering`.  All the work goes on the  server.  It builds an html page which it passes to the client.  JS client takes over, refreshes the page and then sends requests and gets bits of the page back from the server to render when they change.  All the heavy lifting takes place on the server.

Blazor WASM is `Client Side Rendering`.  The client gets a load of JS and WASM files and a small html page.  It has to execute client side code to put it all together and build the page.

Both are Single Page Applications - the initially loaded page is the application.  The client side code just changes out bits of the DOM to update a "page" or move between "pages".

"Pages" are components, not html pages.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind reply.

I knew that SPA should only send html at the beginning. But even if you keep sending html, you can call it SPA because it changes the bit of the DOM to update the "page" or move between the "page", right?

Comment: Which version (Server vs WASM) results in a smaller initial page payload, or are they equivalent?

Comment: @leachryanb - Server, by a large margin.

Answer (score 0):

Blazor has two flavours, Blazor WebAssembly and Blazor Server. Both are used to create SPAs (which are a type of application) and both can be configured to use SSR (which is a technology).
More information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: I think ssr should transfer the entire page and spa should transfer only the necessary parts, so I wonder how the two can coexist.

Comment: @gonak you misunderstand the terms. The actual words matter and explain what they do. Server-side rendering means some pages or parts of the pages are Rendered on the Server. Only SPAs need server-side rendering. All other technologies already render the pages on the server and send the final HTML to the client

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos
Thank you for your kind answer. I think I understand a little bit.
Then, is it possible to call it spa even if I send not only the initial but also continuous altml?
Then, I heard that the characteristic of spa is that it does not blink when changing pages. Does blazer server implement this by modifying only a part of the rendering process through DOM even if html is transmitted?